# Switch compact Android SharedPreferences is not working

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-switch

SharedPreferences in the below code does not work as required. Where am I going wrong? The SharedPreferences is saved on click, and the same is values are being retrieved OnCreate and OnResume in my Android activity.

Code:

```java
mySwitch = (SwitchCompat) findViewById(R.id.atten);
strttime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
endtime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
silent = settings.getBoolean("switchkey", false);
mySwitch.setChecked(silent);

mySwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final SwitchCompat btn = (SwitchCompat) v;
        final boolean switchChecked = silent;

        String message = "Are you sure you want to Logout?";
        if (!btn.isChecked()) {
            message = "Are you sure you want to Login?";
        }
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this, R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle); // Change "this" to `getActivity()` if you're using this on a fragment
        builder.setMessage(message).setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {@Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                // "Yes" button was clicked
                if (switchChecked) {

                    Log.d("You are :", "Checked");

                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("switchkey", true);
                    editor.apply();
                } else {
                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("switchkey", false);
                    editor.apply();
                }
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", null).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: you forgot to mention where you getting wrong value saved by sharedperference in `onCreate` or `onResume`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because of `final boolean switchChecked = silent;` inside your `setOnClickListener`

you passing silent in `switchChecked` and silent is always false due to this
`silent = settings.getBoolean("switchkey", false);`  (if no value is available)

so all you have to do is pass correct value in `switchChecked` like this

`final boolean switchChecked = btn.isChecked();`

because you need to check a user pressed your switch or not

now  `switchChecked` will have right value according user-input

so your code will be

```
  mySwitch = (SwitchCompat) findViewById(R.id.atten);
    strttime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    endtime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    silent = settings.getBoolean("switchkey", false);
    mySwitch.setChecked(silent);

    mySwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final SwitchCompat btn = (SwitchCompat) v;
            final boolean switchChecked = btn.isChecked();

            String message = "Are you sure you want to Logout?";
            if (!btn.isChecked()) {
                message = "Are you sure you want to Login?";
            }
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setMessage(message)
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                            // "Yes" button was clicked
                            if (switchChecked) {

                                Log.d("You are :", "Checked");

                                SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                                editor.putBoolean("switchkey", true);
                                editor.apply();
                            } else {
                                SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                                editor.putBoolean("switchkey", false);
                                editor.apply();
                            }

                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                    .show();

        }

    });
```

Comment: this fixed it!!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you seemingly have two different `SwitchCompat` Views, called `mySwitch` and `btn`? It's hard to tell what you're trying to accomplish.

Anyways, try this instead for grabbing the state of the `SwitchCompat`:

```
builder.setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                        editor.putBoolean("switchkey", mySwitch.isChecked());
                        //or maybe you want btn.isChecked()? I don't know
                        editor.apply();
                    }
```